# PTIJ: What is the Torah preferred brand of cell phone?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I have heard of [Kosher phones](http://forward.com/articles/184099/kosher-smart-phone-arrives-as-ultra-orthodox-tech/?p=all). What do the classic sources (preferably Rishonim or earlier) say about the preferred type and brand of cell phone?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69265/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80768/759

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108332/ and not Purim Torah.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The rule is:

[שלא יוציא אדם דבר מגונה מפיו ולעולם יספר אדם בלשון נקייה](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%99%D7%94)

Never use a [Magna](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/idea-magna-l-2008) and always use a [Nokia](http://company.nokia.com/en).

Answer (score 28):

Hashem himself tends to favour a Windows phone as it says:

`משגיח מן החלונות` - He watches from his Windows [phone]

Comment: Nonono! God Himself tells us to *watch out* for windows phones, as in to avoid them!

Answer (score 27):

A Motorola RAZR is assur, as the paseuk says "you shall not take a RAZR to the corners of your face."

Comment: So you can't take it to your face, but are you allowed to use it with a bluetooth headset? I would say not because "chachlili einayim miyayin ul'ven shinayim mechalav" -- teeth must be white

Comment: @kenzein in any case, the RAZR is certainly not the _preferred_ cell phone. And any good Jew should avoid it just like any good Jew should have a long, white beard.

Answer (score 23):

From davening:

> וּבְסֵפֶר חַיִּים, בְּרָכָה וְשָׁלוֹם, וּפַרְנָסָה טוֹבָה , נִזָּכֵר וְנִכָּתֵב לְפָנֶיךָ, אֲנַחְנוּ וְכָל-עַמְּךָ בֵּית יִשְׂרָאֵל, **לְחַיִּים טוֹבִים** וּלְשָׁלוֹם.

לחיים טובים is clearly a reference to LG, which stands for "Life's Good".

[image: LG: Life's Good]

Answer (score 17):

The gemara in Kesubos tells us that one reason that a bas ysirael ham'oreses l'kohen can't eat terumah is "mishum simphone", indicating that any phone with a SIM is problematic.

Answer (score 14):

1 Kings 18:24  "And call ye on the name of your gods, and I will call on the name of the LORD: and the **God that answereth by fire**, let him be God. And all the people answered and said, It is well spoken."

It might appear that the LORD uses the Amazon Fire.  At least worth considering.
Although, since I'm not an expert in Hebrew, it may be a slight stretch.

Comment: Stretches are what make Purim Torah into Purim Torah :)

Answer (score 12):

[A.K.A. Pella](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YL0K9eJinVE), certainly one of the Rishonim of Jewish a capella, provides two opinions.

> My phone's *hashgacha*'s now uncertified
>   The *vaad* found out that Siri's not a guy
>   They won't let me connect to my Wifi
>   'Cuz Verizon's router's not ten *t'fachim* high
>   **So i'm at a payphone**

They also say:

> Ay ay ay ay
>   You need a kosher phone.
>   Ay ay ay ay
>   You need a glatt kosher phone.

*Glatt* means "smooth", clearly referring to a [Samsung Smooth](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones/SCH-U350ZIAATL) cellphone.

---

This answer inspired me to create a Siri-ous (groan) question about it! ["Siri, sing to me" - Kol Isha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55709/is-using-siri-a-problem-of-kol-isha)

Answer (score 10):

Tosfos [Taanis 29b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=29b&format=text) says that a Tapuach is an Esrog. The Torah calls the Esrog a "Pri Etz Hadar" (a beautiful fruit).

If Apple = Tapuach

and Tapuach = Esrog

and  Esrog = "Beautiful"

Therefore,

Apple is Beautiful!!

PS. If you're going to tell me that the iPhone is the *tree*, I'm going to say that the two taste the same (according to Rashi to Leviticus 23: 40).

Q.E.D

Answer (score 10):

One should not have an iPhone, as the verse in Divrei Hayamim I 21:13 says quite clearly:

> וביד-אדם, אל-אפל
>
> In the hands of man there should not be an Apple

So Apple phones are out.

(And those who are exceedingly pious should avoid Macs and iPads as well.)

Answer (score 8):

The best phone is a Sandalphone. It's what Metatron uses.

Comment: Source? [15 ch]

Comment: Yes, but using Metatron as a source is why Acher became a heretic (chagiga 14). Again, that strikes me as a counter-recommendation.

Answer (score 5):

Urim and Thummim, why not use the recommended ones?

Comment: Unfortunately only the High Priest is allowed to carry that one ;-).

Comment: @Yishai: Is the K''G the only one allowed to *carry* it, or to *use* it?

Comment: @CodeswithHammer http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 2):

To the contrary of what’s been [previously suggested](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80774/), Apples *should* be used. The passuk says (Devarim 20:19):

> כי האדם עץ השדה
>
> For a man is a tree of a field

So when using a phone, which in essence takes the place of the person to whom one is speaking, the phone must be from a “tree of a field.” Therefore, one must have an Apple iPhone, and the carrier must be [Orange](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_S%2EA%2E). For those of us in the States, perhaps AT&T is recommended, as they [bought out Bell Telephone Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Telephone_Company#Acquisition_by_AT&T) and is thus reminiscent of bell peppers.