# PTIJ: When did Avram marry his Iphone?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Breishit 12:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=168&hilite=) says:

> ויקח אברם את שרי אשתו

Avram took Siri, his wife

Siri is the voice used on iPads, iPhones and a number of other Apple devices. I assume that since Avram needed someone easy to travel with, he married an iPhone as opposed to one of these other "girls". I could be wrong about that, so correct me.

But I couldn't find anything in the Torah or the commentary that explains when Avram married his iPhone.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: The premise of your question is an answer to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55508/

Comment: ..and just imagine how beautiful the phone cover was, in order to make the Kings of Egypt and Gerar do what they did.

Comment: @Gary Better watch that language you're using. Siri doesn't understand it ;-)

Comment: I guess our Google girl has better comprehension,  When we ask it "Who (short term for passing wind)?", she says it was her and nobody else in the room.  When we tell it "your(short term for mammalian protuberances) are too small", she thanks us and says they'll be incorporated in an future update.  I'm not kidding - try it!