# PTIJ: Mourning for batteries

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

What are the halachos of mourning over dead batteries?  Do we say Baruch Dayan Haemes?  Is there a period of shiva during which other batteries from the same pack should be removed from their device and surrounded by unrelated batteries?  What about shloshim and the 11/12 months? Are the times affected by the size and capacity of the battery - eg. if your electric car batteries die, is that a longer period than a coin cell?

Please cite sources where possible.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: What about a dead leg? Like, when you sit in the wrong position. Is a Cohen allowed to have a dead leg? Is a Cohen allowed in a building with a dead battery?

Comment: @DoubleAA this seems to be up your alley...

Comment: Of course Rabbi Yehuda in Bava Kama holds that inanimate objects "die" when broken, the chachamim disagree; presumably this question would be according to Rabbi Yehuda.

Comment: @RabbiKaii האבר והבשר המדולדלין באדם טהורים (Ḥullin 9:8).

Comment: @RabbiKaii If you're going to go in that direction, then a Kohen might have to always be in a state of קישוי, the opposite of an אבר מת...

Comment: We could mourn for dead batteries, but when there is Techiyas Hameisim it would be...reVOLTing.

Comment: Related: [Ptij: Halachos of a dead phone?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/111569/1368)

Answer (score 10):

One of the earliest biblical references we have to mourning practices, and in particular the idea of visiting mourners at a *shiva* house comes from the story of the Ma'achah family, who were mourning intensely after removing many dead batteries from their home.

As we learn in [Shmuel II:20:15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Samuel.20.15?lang=he):

> ויבאו ויצרו עליו באבלה בית המעכה וישפכו סללה אל־העיר ותעמד בחל
>
> And they came and joined with him in pain, during the mourning in the Ma'achah home, who had poured out their batteries in the city, making them into a pile.

Comment: +1 For those who don't know, "pile" is also an old term for battery!

Answer (score 6):

Mourning the loss of batteries was in-built into creation itself.

[Bereishis 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.2?lang=bi&aliyot=0) notes how the world was תֹ֙הוּ֙ וָבֹ֔הוּ - "unformed and void"

The [Torah Temimah](https://www.sefaria.org/Torah_Temimah_on_Torah%2C_Genesis.1.2.1?vhe=Torah_Temimah,_Vilna,_1904&lang=bi) writes on this expressly in the footnote:

> **ובטורי** אבן הקשה עליו ופירש פירוש אחר, **אבל** פירושו דחוק כפי שיתבאר להמעין
>
> And the battery was dead (lit. hard) as stone for Him - and this can be explained alternatively as (being in) "a state of mourning", in other words, all its energy had become scarce as will be explained